# secure IoT device/brand publication

Tags: audit, iot

I came across this article: [75 Percent of Bluetooth Smart Locks Can Be Hacked](http://www.tomsguide.com/us/bluetooth-lock-hacks-defcon2016,news-23129.html) when I was looking for IoT stuff for my home.

tl;dr is they tested 16 bluetooth smart locks and eventually only two were hack proof (as of the last update). The two left were padlocks.

Are there any resources/groups that have something like the above article, but not limited to smart locks? All I've found are articles that say so and so device security is bad.

What I'm looking for is to make my house smart, but not easily hacked. I'm trying to do so by looking for a site that reviews the security of IoT stuff and gives them a score. There are a few groups that are working on five star ratings or certifications but I'm not aware of anything that is already published.

*I realize this sounds like a list question, but I'm not asking for recommendations. I'm looking for a trustworthy resource I can lean on for good information. If this isn't the right place to post this, some direction to where it would be on topic would be appreciated.*

Comment: although not asking for a list, it's asking for a site/service/product

Answer (score 0):

There are a few folks doing IoT security reviews, but not too many of them out there just yet. Matthew Garrett has gained a bit of noteriety for reviewing a few products:

http://mjg59.dreamwidth.org/tag/advogato (reviews are in among other posts and also posted to Amazon)

Some of them to amusing effect:

https://www.theverge.com/circuitbreaker/2016/7/5/12096520/bad-amazon-review-product-pulled-auyou

Several vendors are trying to hawk <strike>snakeoil</strike> products to protect you from the scary IoT devices in the meanwhile. Hope they work on microwaves too:

https://us.norton.com/core

https://www.bitdefender.com/box/